# Idiomatic transitive qualification

Tags: idioms, syntactic-analysis, french

How would you concisely/idiomatically say what follows

> By the very level at which some objects are implied, the story that follows and implies these objects necessarily is a story of this level.

I guess that I am not clear at all. Another (and more archetyped) example:

> Given the macroeconomic scale at which these indicators are computed, then what we do with these variables is necessarily related to macroeconomics

?

---

Clarification/simplification attempt.

Does the last example above sound "English" or is there a more idiomatic way of saying this? Actually, starting the sentence with *Given the [...] at which [...]* is a formulation which is somehow native in other languages, but I guess that is sounds inappropriate in English.

PS: i could make my question clearer in my native language...

Comment: In French, they are a lot of tortured way of saying things that actually can prove to be very useful when one wants to share proposition-contracted ideas. I actually spend most of my time struggling to find their English counterparts which, I am almost certain, do exist. For those who want to know, the idea expressed above, can be forumlated in french as: `De par l'échelle macroéconomique à laquelle ces indicateurs sont calculés`.

Comment: Machine generated translations do not always make sense, let alone be grammatical. AFAIK this is no way to go about understanding a French passage.

Comment: @Kris. This is not machine-translated. BTW, not sure to understand your point.

Comment: De par l'échelle macroéconomique à laquelle ces indicateurs sont calculés = By the macroeconomic scale at which these indicators are calculated (according to Google Translate). Idiomatically, in English, one might say:  **In light of** "X", then "X". Which may also be stated as a question.